# Openpyxl Issue: Deleting row not moving merged cells

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am having an issue with openpxyl deleting a row and not moving the merged cells up. For example, in the first picture, I have two merged cells with values Alex & Bob. When I delete row 2, Alex gets moved up to a single cell, Bob gets deleted, and the position of the merged cells stay in the same spot while the remainder of the data points get moved up. When normally working with excel outside of Python, the merged cells would simply move up with the rest of the data. It appears that openpxyl wants to move up the data values but keep the position of the merged cells the same. What is the work around for this? Thank you in advance!!

Before deleting row 2:

[image]

```
ws.delete_rows(2)
```

When I delete row 2 the following happens:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcdPF.png]

How it should look like if you were deleting row two manually in excel:
[image]

Comment: You have to do this yourself, the same as with formulae or references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue when removing columns, merged cells that intersect such a column ended up being unchanged.

This works in a more satisfactory manner.

The code provides the `delete_row()` function, which can be used to imitate Excel behavior, and move merged cells accordingly:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
from openpyxl.utils.cell import _get_column_letter
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange


def delete_row(target_row):
   # Assuming that the workbook from the example is the first worksheet in a file called "in.xlsx"
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('in.xlsx')
   ws = workbook.worksheets[0]

   affected_cells = [] # array for storing merged cells that need to be moved

   row = target_row # specify the row that we want to delete
   sheet_boundary = [4,6] # specify how far to search for merged cells in the sheet in the format of [ max_col, max_row ]

   ## Define a range of cells that are below the deleted row
   # top left corner of the range; will be A2
   tl_corner = "A"+str(row)
   # bottom right corner of the row; will be D6
   br_corner = _get_column_letter(sheet_boundary[0]) + str(sheet_boundary[1])

   target_row_range_string = tl_corner+":"+br_corner

   # express all cells in the row that is to be deleted as object CellRange from openpyxl
   target_range = CellRange(range_string=target_row_range_string)


   # loop over all merged cells in the sheet
   for merged_cell_range in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
      # if merged_cell is within target_range add current merged cell to 'affected_cells'
      if merged_cell_range.issubset(target_range):
         print("Cell '"+str(merged_cell_range)+"' is within range of '"+str(target_range)+"'")
         affected_cells.append(merged_cell_range)


   # unmerge all affected cells
   for cell in affected_cells:
         # get a tuple of coordinates, instead of Xlsx notation
         cell_range = range_boundaries(cell.coord)
         print("'"+str(cell)+"' ---> '"+str(cell_range)+"'")

         # unmerge the affected cell
         ws.unmerge_cells(start_column = cell_range[0], start_row = cell_range[1],
                          end_column = cell_range[2], end_row = cell_range[3])


   # perform row deletion as usual
   ws.delete_rows(row)

   # merged all affected cells
   for cell in affected_cells:
         # get a tuple of coordinates, instead of Xlsx notation
         cell_range = range_boundaries(cell.coord)
         # merge back the affected cell, while lifting it up by one row
         ws.merge_cells(start_column = cell_range[0], start_row = cell_range[1]-1,
                        end_column = cell_range[2], end_row = cell_range[3]-1)

   # save the edited workbook
   workbook.save('out.xlsx')


# call our custom function, specifying the row you want to delete
delete_row(2)
```

This finds all the merged cells that intersect the `target_range`, a range that starts with the deleted row and ends with the range defined by `sheet_boundary` and first unmerges them.

Only merged cells that are fully within `target_range` are changed.
If a part of the merged cell is within the `target_range`, then no operations are performed on that cell.

Then it deletes the desired row, and merges back all the affected cells, while taking into account that they have been moved up one row.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary but unsatisfactory fix.

If I use the following code:

```
for merged_cell in ws.merged_cell.ranges:
    merged_cell.shift(0,-1)
ws.delete_rows(2)
```

This will fix my problem and move the merged cells up. However, the one issue I have with this code is that it moves up ALL merged cells in the file. If I want to only moved the merged cells up in column A, I am not sure how to reduce the list of ranges to only include those in a.

For example, the following code doesn't work but highlights what I am trying to accomplish with specificity:

```
ws['A'].merged_cells.ranges
```